# Why do non-retina macs load the 2x version of a picture element?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, retina-display, picturefill

Im using picturefill 2.0 and the picture element with some dynamic urls.

```
<picture alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <source srcset="<?php echo $tablet; ?>, <?php echo $tablet; ?> 2x" media="(max-width: 950px)">
    <source srcset="<?php echo $laptop; ?>, <?php echo $laptop; ?> 2x" media="(max-width: 1440px)">
    <img srcset="<?php echo $desktop; ?>, <?php echo $desktop; ?> 2x">
</picture>
```

I have created an image that is twice the size and used if I detect a retina display via a cookie.

If no retina is detected then those variables are just the normal sized images.

The problem I'm having is that non-retina macs are loading the `<?php echo $desktop; ?> 2x` image from the picture element.

If I remove the 2x option from the picture element images load fine.

Shouldn't that image only be loaded by devices with retina displays?

Comment: can you please enter devicePixelRatio inside your console and look what will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Don't output the same image as both 1x and 2x, based on what you detect. You don't need to detect anything. Just output your 1x image as 1x and your 2x image as 2x. The browser is free to download any image in `srcset` as it sees fit.